# What is the point of Impa's choice?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Zelda BOTW, when you first meet Impa, she says that Zelda left a message for you, but that she is afraid that the knowledge may be **"too much to bear while you are still without your memories"**.

At this point, you can either refuse to hear it right now and leave (and if you do so, the main quest related to meeting Impa will not advance) or hear the message anyway.

Now, I figured I would try waiting to "recover my memories" before hearing the message, and set out to try and do that.

However, after researching for a bit around the internet, I learned that, to recover my memories, I needed to get the "Camera Glyph" which will be given to you at the Hateno Ancient Lab, but the guy there will only give me the related quest if I have "Impa's Authorisation" (which I will only get if I listen to the aforementioned message!)

Is there any other way to recover your memories, and if not, is there any point that I may have missed to Impa giving you the choice?

Comment: You get memories as you complete the divine beast sub-quests. Not sure if that causes Impa's dialogue to change.

Comment: @SableDreamer I already had the memory gotten from the Zora divine beast quest (Mipha's touch) but she didn't mention anything about it. Maybe if you do all four divine beasts before talking to her something changes... Might try that out

Comment: Actually I got the Camera Glyph without ever having been to Kakariko.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the "point" is that you don't actually need to accept and accomplish all "main" quests. You can just walk away and not collect memories if you want.